# Ошибка - TypeError: place_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку? Перелистал все ответы в инете, так пока и не понял.

```
class Btn:

    button = Button

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, height=80, width=60):
        self.text = text
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def conclusion(self): #появление кнопки
        self.button(text=self.text,
                    background='#555',
                    foreground='#ccc',
                    font='16'
                    )

        self.button.place(x=self.x, y=self.y, height=self.height, width=self.width) #вот тут ошибка
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `button` это не объект, а тип `Button`, подробнее:

- `button = Button` -- это в поле `button` сохранена ссылка на тип `Button`
- `self.button(` это тоже самое, что `Button(`, т.е. создание и возврат объекта
- `self.button.place` тоже самое, что `Button.place(`, т.е. обращение к методу через его тип

Решение:

```
class Btn:
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, height=80, width=60):
        self.text = text
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.button = None

    def conclusion(self):  # Появление кнопки
        self.button = Button(
            text=self.text,
            background='#555',
            foreground='#ccc',
            font='16'
        )
        self.button.place(x=self.x, y=self.y, height=self.height, width=self.width)
```